# How to import Underscore into my Ember CLI addon as a module?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-addon

I'm trying to import Underscore as a named module into my Ember CLI addon. Looking at the [Standard AMD Asset](http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-amd-asset) section of the guides, it seems this should work:

```
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/underscore/underscore.js', {
  exports: {
    'underscore': ['default']
  }
});
```

Here's the line from [Underscore's source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1543):

```
define('underscore', [], function() {
  return _;
});
```

I tried to import it in one of my files, `/addon/utils/class.js`:

```
import _ from 'underscore';
```

and got an error:

> Could not find module `underscore` imported from `ember-cli-mirage/utils/class`

What'd I do wrong?

Comment: Weird, I attempted the same thing, but I didn't run into the error. The app.import statement initializes _ as a global in my app, whereas if I try to do `import _ from 'underscore'` the app won't load at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [problem](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1585):
`if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)`

`define.amd` is [not](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/blob/master/loader.js#L67) defined in ember-cli's loader.js.

Solutions:

- Wrap it yourself.
- Use browserify to do the wrapping for you
- Use LoDash instead (this is what I suggest - easy, peazy, problem solved & you get time for an extra round of mojitos at the beach bar ;)).

Comment: nice, thanks! fyi, I believe [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) will soon lessen these pains points, since underscore also exports a commonjs module